# How should I pass langchain callback to nestjs's sse return?

Tags: nestjs, server-sent-events, openai-api, langchain

```
type Typescript
@Post()
  @Sse('sse')
  async createChat(
    @Res() res,
    @Body() createChatRequestDto: CreateChatRequestDto,
  ) {
    const { chain, sanitizedQuestion, histories } =
      await this.chatService.createChat(createChatRequestDto);

    await chain.call(
      {
        question: sanitizedQuestion,
        chat_history: histories || [],
      },
      [
        {
          handleLLMNewToken(token: string) {
            res.write(token);
          },
        },
      ],
    );
  }
```

I found a way to get the answer through streaming in langchain. I don't know how to forward this to the front using nestjs's server side event. Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to how you're writing the data to the response. In SSE, data should be sent in a specific format. Here's how you can modify your createChat method to correctly use SSE with LangChain:

```
@Post()
@Sse('sse')
async createChat(
  @Res() res: Response,
  @Body() createChatRequestDto: CreateChatRequestDto,
) {
  const { chain, sanitizedQuestion, histories } =
    await this.chatService.createChat(createChatRequestDto);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  res.flushHeaders();

  await chain.call(
    {
      question: sanitizedQuestion,
      chat_history: histories || [],
    },
    [
      {
        handleLLMNewToken(token: string) {
          res.write(`data: ${token}\n\n`); // write the token as an SSE event
        },
      },
    ],
  );

  res.end();
}
```

In this code, you're setting the necessary headers for SSE and then using res.write to send data to the client. Each message is prefixed with **data:** and suffixed with two newline characters (**\n\n**) which is the format required for SSE